# problemas con la libreria full page js

Tags: jquery

estoy teniendo problemas con una libreria llamada full page que hace que cuando se cargue la pagina se me baja el scroll automaticamente a la seccion de contactos que esta en el footer, me podian ayudar con el error, estaria agradecido con la ayuda dejare codigo

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">{{ __('inicio') }}</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">{{ __('eventos') }}</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">{{ __('Promociones') }}</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a class="nav-link" href="#firstPage">{{ __('Contactanos') }}</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>


<div class="container" id="fullpage">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 section">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Contactanos</h5>
        <form id="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Nombres">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Apellidos">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Telefono</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Telefono">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Correo Electronico</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Alguien@example.com">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn" style="background-color: orange">Enviar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Y con esta setencia por medio de jquery activo el scroll

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            menu: '#menu',
            anchors: ['firstPage'],
            autoScrolling: false,
            licenseKey: 'OPEN-SOURCE-GPLV3-LICENSE'
        });
})
```

Comment: Puedes colocar todo tu código completo para poder ayudarte? por que en ningún lado logro visualizar el id #fullpage en tu html. De hecho la llamada a la librería no es igual a lo que aparece en la documentación, estas haciendo una llamada con `jQuery` pero en la doc se indica que debes crear una instancia de `fullpage`

Comment: pero si miras mas detalladamente en `github` tambien se puede hacer llamado con `jquery` @vcasas

Comment: Cierto, acabo de revisar. ¿Y con respecto a la primera pregunta...?

Comment: cuando hago el llamado por `jquery` una vez se cargue la pagina el scroll se baja a la parte de donde esta el formulario y mi punto es q cuando le den click al boton de contactenos se baje con el efecto @vcasas

Comment: Te pregunte una cosa pero me respondes con otra cosa...

Comment: ahh verdad, lo siento, por mas q lo hago ya sea con instancia o por llamado de `jquery`  de una u otra forma no me quiere funcionar el codigo y no se que pueda ser @vcasas

Comment: a la primera pregunta me refiero a esto *Puedes colocar todo tu código completo para poder ayudarte? por que en ningún lado logro visualizar el id #fullpage en tu html*

Comment: pero si ya lo hice bro esta al final del cierre del `</nav>` @vcasas